# javascript: confuse about parameter in function

Tags: arrays, function, parameters

I have several function with unsure parameter's count, and I have an array like `arr=[1, 2, 3, 4]`

and I want pass the array's head number into the function as parameter

```
fn1(arr[0], arr[1]);

fn1(arr[0], arr[1], arr[1]);

fn1(arr[0]);

fn1(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
```

still now I have to do it by hand, but I want do it in automatically with loop or something, through counting the function's parameter count, and pass the array's head several ones by itself

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you pass the array as an argument like this:

```
function myFunction(arguments)
{
    // set the parameters manually
    var arg1 = arguments[0];
    [...]

    // do your stuff ...
}

var arr=[1, 2, 3, 4];

myFunction(arr);
```

Or you can do this (should be what you want):

```
function myFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
{
    // dump arguments
    document.write(arg1);
    document.write(arg2);
    document.write(arg3);
    document.write(arg4);
}

var arr=[1, 2, 3, 4];

myFunction.apply(null, arr);
```